# An example of matrix with spectral radius < 1

Tags: matrices

I am trying to run some tests on Jacobie iterative method for solving linear systems.
However, I have a problem with finding such matrix $A$, which:

- isn't diagonally dominant
- when we take two matrices $D$ and $R$, such that $D$ is diagonal from $A$ (so $d_{ii} = a_{ii}$ and rest of the fields are zeros); and $R$ which is the rest (so, $R = A - D$), then, spectral radius of matrix $D^{-1}R < 1$.

Can someone have an example of such matrix? Or is there any hints to create this kind of matrix?

Comment: What form of diagonal dominance do you want?

Comment: I *don't* want it to be strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant.

Comment: Maybe you should write down the definition of _what_ you want...
I figured that the toeplitz Matrix with $2$ on the diagonal and $-1$ on the first subdiagonals (symmetric), which is the finite difference approximation of the Laplacian with zero boundary conditions can be solved this way (convergence is slow, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"These are the matrices I was looking for".*

$$
A =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & -2 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  2 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

It's not diagonally dominant, and it also satisfies second requirement.